# MeteorJS email configuration SSL

Tags: email, ssl, meteor

I am trying to send emails from Meteor JS and took the simplest approach found in the documentation. However, sending fails and I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception while invoking method 'sendEmail' Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Object.Future.wait (/usr/lib64/meteor/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:322:15)
at smtpSend (app/packages/email/email.js:69:43)
at Object.Email.send (app/packages/email/email.js:111:7)
at Meteor.methods.sendEmail (app/server/email.js:7:11)
at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method.exception (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:593:30)
at _.extend.withValue (app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:33:19)
at app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:592:46
at _.extend.withValue (app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:33:19)
at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:591:37)
at _.extend.processMessage.processNext (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:484:43)
- - - - -
at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)
```

I provide my email settings in bootstrap.js in the server folder via this line:

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://user@gmail.com:password@smtp.googlemail.com:465"
```

I am pretty sure I also have to switch on SSL somewhere, but I do not know how (I could probably use Node's email.js alone).

Comment: PLease add this as your own answer in case someone else comes up to it too

Comment: I got the same error, but my issue was that my corporate firewall was blocking port 25. Switching to port 587 resolved the timeout. This command can be used to test connectivity to the SMTP server and port: `nc email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 587`

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself - it was not the lack of setting the SSL option, but the first '@gmail.com' in MAIL_URL. The correct line is:

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://user:password@smtp.googlemail.com:465"
```

Comment: From original question.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using @gmail.com (and sometimes unavoidable, e.g. in case of google aps), but you've got to url-encode the first @.